# Is there an Amazon.com API to retrieve Amazon Keyword volume data

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hello all I am looking for an Amazon API that can be used to pull volume of a keyword from Amazon? Is there is any API available?

This website is doing the same but not sure what services or APIs they will be using: https://www.merchantwords.com/

Comment: I don't know an API doing this, I can only imagine they are calculating the data from the salesrank... If you find the API, please tell me!

Comment: thanks for your hint. i will for sure if I find an API.

Comment: Have you ever figured out the API or the method to solve your problem?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @WorieN Unfortunately no. At the moment my project was abandoned.

Comment: @ImranKhan any update?

Answer (score 2):

As Amazon does not publish these numbers, my guess it's just applied statistics, based on search/Amazon ranking click through distributions and the way the products Amazon rankings fluctuate.